# CSS: Image 100% Height - auto width - constrained by viewport

Tags: css

I need an image to stretch to 100% height of its parent and have an auto height - but i dont want the width to be larger than the view port and want the image to keep its proportions.

At the moment I have the following less -

```
img{
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
    max-height:none;
    max-width:auto!important;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: auto!important;
    margin-right: auto!important;
}
```

Comment: You can have a look on: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: _“to stretch to 100% height of its parent and have an auto height”_ – no what do you want, 100% _or_ auto? Demanding both at the same time makes little sense.